# ceaser cipher encrypt/decrypt javascript giving string index error

Tags: javascript, java

I was given an assignment to create a Java program in Jgrasp that encrypts and then decrypts a message using ceaser's cipher. Our teacher gave us a shell and examples all of which I used to create the code. The problem is that the code compiles fine, but when trying to run it, I get a Sting Index Error. I somewhat understand what the error means, but I'm at a lost as to how to resolve it. If someone could explain to me what is causing the error and how to resolve it, it would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Thanks to Spectric for pointing out the error in my for loops! The problem I have now is that I can't seem to get the message to output in all caps even though I used String MESSAGE = message.toUpperCase(); . Also I added output lines and while the encrypted message displays the decrypted message is just blank. Lastly when spaces are added to the message I get an error, how do you account for non character inputs when doing the encryption/decryption? I'm assuming it is some form of if statement, but I've been unable to crack it. Appreciate the help!

**CODE:**

```
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class CaesarCipherShell {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
          Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
          run(kb);
              
       }
       public static void run(Scanner kb)
       {
         System.out.println("How many times would you like to use the app? ");
          int count = kb.nextInt();
         for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
         {
          System.out.println("Please enter a message: ");
           String message = kb.next();
          System.out.print("Please enter a key: ");
           int key = kb.nextInt();
          encrypt(message, key);
          decrypt(message, key);
         }
       }
       public static String encrypt(String message, int key) 
       {
          String MESSAGE = message.toUpperCase();
          String result = "";
          for(int i = 0; i < MESSAGE.length(); i++) 
          {
             char c = MESSAGE.charAt(i);
             if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
             {
                c = (char)(c + key);
                if(c > 'Z')
                {
                   c = (char)(c - 26);
                }
                else
                {
                   c = (char)(c + 26);
                }
             }
          result = c + result;     
          }
       System.out.println("Encrypted message:" + result);
       return result;
       }
       public static String decrypt(String MESSAGE, int key) 
       {
          String result = "";
          for(int i = 0; i < MESSAGE.length(); i++)
          {
             char c = MESSAGE.charAt(i);
             if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
             {
                c = (char)(c - key);
                if(c < 'A')
                {
                   int diff = 'A' - c;
                   c = (char)('Z' - diff + 1);
                }
                else if (c > 'Z')
                {
                   int diff = 'Z' - c;
                   c = (char)('A' + diff + 1);
                }
             result = c + result;
             }                          
          
          }
       System.out.println ("Decrypted message:" +result);
       return result;   
       }
    }
```

Output

```
     ----jGRASP exec: java CaesarCipherShell
How many times would you like to use the app? 
2
Please enter a message: 
hello
Please enter a key: 5
Encrypted message:nkkdg
Decrypted message:
Please enter a message: 
i like turtles
Please enter a key: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at CaesarCipherShell.run(CaesarCipherShell.java:19)
    at CaesarCipherShell.main(CaesarCipherShell.java:7)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation
```

Comment: In your for loop, your index goes to message.length which is bigger than the max index which is message.length - 1 since the indices start at zero. You can fix it by making the comparison strictly inferior instead of inferior or equal.

Comment: For the key, you have to use `int key = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());` because it assumes that you typed the number after you typed "i like turtles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop in your code responsible for looping through every character in your String is broken.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= MESSAGE.length(); i++)
```

Since you perform `char c = MESSAGE.charAt(i);` every time, once `i` is `MESSAGE.length()`, it will throw the String Index Error because the last character of a String in Java is the length - 1 (as index starts at 0).

In this case, your code should be:

```
public class CaesarCipherShell {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      run(kb);
          
   }
   public static void run(Scanner kb)
   {
     System.out.println("How many times would you like to use the app? ");
      int count = kb.nextInt();
     for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
     {
      System.out.println("Please enter a message: ");
       String message = kb.next();
      System.out.print("Please enter a key: ");
       int key = kb.nextInt();
      encrypt(message, key);
      decrypt(message, key);
     }
   }
   public static String encrypt(String message, int key) 
   {
      String MESSAGE = message.toUpperCase();
      String result = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < MESSAGE.length(); i++) 
      {
         char c = MESSAGE.charAt(i);
         if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
         {
            c = (char)(c + key);
            if(c > 'Z')
            {
               c = (char)(c - 26);
            }
            else
            {
               c = (char)(c + 26);
            }
         }
      result = c + result;     
      }
   return result;
   }
   public static String decrypt(String MESSAGE, int key) 
   {
      String result = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < MESSAGE.length(); i++)
      {
         char c = MESSAGE.charAt(i);
         if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
         {
            c = (char)(c - key);
            if(c < 'A')
            {
               int diff = 'A' - c;
               c = (char)('Z' - diff + 1);
            }
            else if (c > 'Z')
            {
               int diff = 'Z' - c;
               c = (char)('A' + diff + 1);
            }
         result = c + result;
         }                          
      
      }
   return result;   
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Totally missed the = signs in my for loops. Everything runs great now, but I do have several small problems now. First the message.toUpperCase(); doesn't seem to be converting the message to all caps in my output. Second, while I am getting the encrypted message to output, the decrypted message just outputs blank. Also how do you account for non character inputs in the message such as spaces? I updated the code in the post and added the the new output. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @punkedoutleppy I'll take a look